# How to show these two spaces are not homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Consider the set $D=\{\frac{1}{n}:n=1,2,...\}\cup\{0\}$ and let $X=C(D,\mathbb{R})$ with $d_X(f,g)=\sup_{x\in A}|f(x)-g(x)|$. Show that $X$ and $l^\infty(\mathbb{N})$ are not homeomorphic.

I tried to find a topological property not shared by two spaces but I cannot find one. They are both metric spaces. Is there any other methods I can try?

Comment: I assume $X=C(D,\mathbb R)$.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip Yes, $X=C(D,\mathbb{R})$, sorry for the typo.

Comment: Try to think about what distinguishes the two spaces. If $D$ didn't exclude the $0$, would they be homeomorphic?

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip Okay, I got it. Since $f\in X$ is continuous, $\{f(\frac{1}{n})\}$ converges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The space $C(D,\mathbb R)$ can be identified with  the space $c$ of all convergent sequences of real numbers with the sup norm. Sequences of rational numbers which are eventually constant  form a countable dense set. Since $l^{\infty}$ is not separable, the two spaces are not homeomorphic.

Comment: Thank you. Countability is indeed a topological property.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $l^\infty(\mathbb N)$ is not separable. For example, distinct binary sequences are at distance $1$ from each other, and there are uncountably of these. So the strategy would be to show $C(D,\mathbb R)$ is separable.